# Merging tags yields 302 error

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, tags, tag-merge-utility

I've merged one tag into another, but the new tag's /synonyms page gives me an HTTP 302 error pointing to the old tag's /synonyms page (which itself of course gives a 404 error).

(https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tags/mishlei/synonyms is the 302, to https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tags/mishlei-proverbs/synonyms, the 404.)

Besides the fact that this bug needs fixing, I'd appreciate any recommendations on how to add a synonym to this tag until such time as the bug is fixed.

---

**Update:** Now [that 302 page](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tags/mishlei/synonyms) is (still a 302 but) redirecting to *itself*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see a tag synonym from [mishlei](/questions/tagged/mishlei) to itself in https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?filter=active&tab=newest

As a mod, the simplest thing to do here is to nuke the offending synonym.

I just fixed the offending code that caused the redirect loop, in future if this happens we will get a warning in our log - users will not get any annoying redirect loops.